# Is there a way to increase or decrease the amount of purchased parallel jobs via API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Since Azure DevOps doesn't support auto-scaling of the MS hosted agents, I would like to be able to adjust it via automation. But I can't find any APIs that enable adjusting the paid parallel jobs for MS hosted agents. Does it exist?

[Screenshot of the parallel jobs billing section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP0ji.png)

I know that I could spin up an Azure VM Scale Set, but the hosted agents are much cheaper, and I don't need to maintain the hosted agents so I would like to take advantage of them if possible.

I've reviewed the Azure DevOps API documentation. I've also tried to grab the API from the network tab in dev tools which gave me `https://azdevopscommerce.dev.azure.com/[GUID]/_apis/AzComm/MeterResource` but I get an unauthorized error when using the same headers as other Azure DevOps APIs.

Comment: I doubt it. Microsoft wants you to pay for your maximum desired amount of parallelism.